# Anchor tag not working with dynamic table

Tags: javascript

The anchor link is not working when I construct a dynamic table with javascript.

Code:

```
            $(".genareteEmail").click(
                    function() {
                        alert("sdsds");
                        var incidentNo = $(this).attr('dataId');

                        $.ajax({
                            url : "generate?incident=" + incidentNo,
                            method : 'GET',
                            success : function(data) {
                                var subject = data;
                                var content = subject.split("END");
                                try {

                                    var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject(
                                            "Outlook.Application");
                                    var nameSpace = outlookApp
                                            .getNameSpace("MAPI");
                                    mailFolder = nameSpace
                                            .getDefaultFolder(6);
                                    mailItem = mailFolder.Items
                                            .add('IPM.Note.FormA');
                                    mailItem.Subject = content[3];
                                    mailItem.cc = content[2];
                                    mailItem.To = content[1];
                                    mailItem.HTMLBody += content[0];
                                    var insp = mailItem.GetInspector;
                                    var mySigline = mailItem.HTMLBody;
                                    mailItem.display(0);
                                } catch (e) {
                                    alert(e);
                                    // act on any error that you get
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    });

             $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
                 callMe();

                }); 

            function callMe() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "ajaxTicketInfo",
                    type : 'GET',
                    error : function() {

                    },
                    success : function(result) {
                        var ticketCount = result.length;

                        var mytable = $('<table></table>');//.attr({ id: "basicTable" });
                        var rows = ticketCount;
                        var cols = 2;
                        var tr = [];
                     $('<tr></tr>').html("<th>Incidents</th><th>Mail Generation</th>").appendTo(mytable);
                        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                            var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
                            for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                                if(j== 0){
                                $('<td></td>').text(result[i] + " "+ Math.random()).appendTo(row);
                                }else{

                                    //var aTag = $('<a></a>').attr({ dataId: result[i] });

                                    $('<td></td>').html('<a class="genareteEmail" href="#" dataId ="'+result[i]+'">Generate Email</a>').appendTo(row);
                                    /* $('<td></td>').text("Generate Mail").append(row); */

                                }

                            }

                        }
                        $("#box").html(mytable);
                    },
                     cache: false
                });
            };

            setInterval(callMe, 900000);
        });



<body>


<h1>Acknowledgement Mail Generation</h1>

<div>
    <div>
        Next Refresh will be in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id = "btnSubmit">Refresh</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="box">
   <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><th>Incidents</th><th>Mail Generation</th></tr>
      <tr><td>INC000013610276 0.15926314527814805</td><td>
      <a class="generateEmail" href="#" dataid="INC000013610276">Generate 
            Email</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td>INC000013608353 0.7894190043310691</td><td>
      <a class="generateEmail" href="#" dataid="INC000013608353">Generate 
            Email</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td>INC000013594620 0.8572899023472066</td><td>
      <a class="generateEmail" href="#" dataid="INC000013594620">Generate 
            Email</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td>INC000013592053 0.02202170976246076</td><td>
      <a class="generateEmail" href="#" dataid="INC000013592053">Generate Email</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

As per my code when I click the corresponding anchor link the .genarateEmail jquery need to be executed. But the click functionality is not working.

Can anybody help me where I made wrong while creating the dynamic table.

Comment: Do you actually have a `class="genareteEmail"` in your html? or do you have `class='generateEmail'` WITHOUT the typos?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake, I just edited the HTML part, but still facing the issue.

Comment: where/how are you running the js code? if it's not in a `$.ready()` block, or executing BEFORE the html is parsed, you'll attach to nothing because that css class doesn't exist in the DOM yet.

Comment: I did not add that part here. I have it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

All the events should be bound once the document is ready. Hence include your method within the document ready as commented by @Mark B

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".genareteEmail").click( function(){
      //Your logic

   })
})
```